# Como simular um clique no Linkedin com selenium. Problema: id dinâmico / usa ember

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, emberjs

Bom dia, estou tentando clicar no botão 'Exibir mais' no campo das competências mas sem êxito algum.
O xpath é dinâmico, e por class também não funciona.
O botão parece estar escondida de algum modo.

Tentei por xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember2605"]/button/span[2]/li-icon/svg/path').click()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Olá, aparentemente o Linkedin te força a usar o Xpath, já que o Selenium (hoje!,24/04/18) não te permite achar por classes compostas.

portanto você vai precisar procurar por:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'ember']))
```

procure todos os elementos que cuja xpath comece com 'ember'. Observe que o uso do Xpath continua o mesmo, então você poderá usar como sempre: adicionando mais mais caminhos a frente.

O que vai se tornar problemático pq vai trazer coisas inúteis junto, mas é o que resolve.

Espero ter ajudado.

Att, Willy do passado.